# In org-mode, how do I remove the "Validate XHTML 1.0" message from HTML export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode 7.8, how do I remove the "Validate XHTML 1.0" message at the bottom of the page?

Its neighbours can be removed with:

> #+OPTIONS:   author:nil email:nil creator:nil timestamp:nil

but I can't find the equivalent for the "Validate XHTML 1.0" message.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way is to change the value of the `org-export-html-validation-link` variable to nil:

```
(setq org-export-html-validation-link nil)
```

As of org version 8.0, use:

```
(setq org-html-validation-link nil)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no #+OPTIONS: switch though?

Comment: I tried using `#+BIND: org-export-html-validation-link nil` but couldn't get that to work. Setting the variable in .emacs works though.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to directly edit the `org-export-html-postamble-format` variable and get rid of the `%v` stuff

Comment: `org-export-html-validation-link` was renamed with `org-html-validation-link` as of 8.0.

Comment: @BryanLuby: setting `org-export-allow-bind-keyword` to t should make it work then

Answer (score 15):

I used the following line in my org file:

```
#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil
```

but that removes more than just the validation link. Using `html-validation-link` instead didn't have the expected result.

Comment: This is documented here: http://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html

Answer (score 3):

You can also use local variables if you only want to do this for some files by adding the following to the end of the `org` file.

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-validation-link: nil
# End:
```